# Installing GWT plugin with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am trying to use GWT and I am very new to it. Following the doc, I tried to install the GWT plugin for Eclipse but then I have an error message :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r37
  (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r37)
 Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r37
  (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r37)
  requires 'org.mortbay.jetty.server 0.0.0' but it could not be found"
```

I tried to find to what `org.mortbay.jetty.server` could deal with, but I didn't find. Does anyone know?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

Comment: Sure, I followed it steps by steps

Comment: download a fresh version again and try.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because you're attempting to use the latest Juno build, 4.2, with a plugin link for 3.7.

Use the following update site: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Everything should work fine now.

Comment: This is incorrect link. Instead of downloads it points to installation procedures.

Comment: @codingscientist You are supposed to add and enable this link to the "Available software sources" list within Eclipse and use it to download the necessary files from the "Install new software" option.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I think it's because I was using eclipse Juno (the google documentation says to use indigo). The jetty project recently moved under the eclipse umbrella, and the jetty bundles (org.mortbay.jetty.server) were renamed (see http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/jetty/). Thus the 3.7 google plugins wouldn't be able to resolve dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want the earlier (3.x) version of the plugin try copying the plugins directory of some team member who already has that version of the plugin installed. I couldn't imagine the reason why google decomittioned the previous version of the plugin!