# unable to install google plugin for eclipse juno

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to install google gwt tool on eclipse for that i  go to HELP--->Install new Software---> in text area i used this link

```
Google Update Site for Eclipse 4.2 - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
```

then whenever i checked Google Plugin for eclipse (required) and hit next it shows

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. 
Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42 
(com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42) 
Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42 
(com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42) requires 
'org.objectweb.asm 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

i didn't understand what and where is the problem coming .

Comment: Please format your error messages properly. They are unreadable otherwise.  I did it this time.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem just now trying to download Google Plugin for Eclipse.  I was running into the same error where it was complaining about:

"Cannot complete install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 bla bla bla..."

This question is a duplicate ([Installing GWT plugin with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285757/installing-gwt-plugin-with-eclipse)) but Ill lay it out for you anyways :)

I followed these steps that I found on https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2 and it worked fine :) The only thing different is that I downloaded from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 INSTEAD of from (as when was throwing an error) http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin.3.7. When I used 3.7 I got the same error you are having now. 4.2 it's all gravy.

Also, I am doing this on a fresh Juno installation. Like, I literally downloaded it from the Eclipse site right 2 minutes ago, installed it, ran an update (there was one update for Eclipse Google Plugin) and then I i got the errors and fixed the issue.

In fact, I got my answers here: [Installing GWT plugin with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285757/installing-gwt-plugin-with-eclipse) so thank this dude. Not me.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is missing the `org.objectweb.asm` bundle.  I'm a little surprised that this is not installed by the google plugin by default.  There are many places to get it, but I know you can get the bundle from orbit:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130517111416/repository/
```

Copy the link and add it to your list of update sites.  Then try to install the google plugin again.  Make sure that you have "Contact all update sites" checked.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have Indigo Eclipse and trying for Juno Eclipse plugin.

Refer to link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse

Look at plugin links for Indigo and Juno and act accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin installation failed, you may have problems with the Eclipse version installed that might be outdated (my problem). 
For more information about upgrading Eclipse, see [Upgrading Existing Eclipse Features](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F?).